# Getting admission in the US after a BSc and MSc from India

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, india

Since the US considers BSc and MSc together to be equivalent to a B.Tech degree (or any 4 year degree) how should I report my result?
With both degrees from different institutes and in unrelated subjects, how do I add the score and present it as equivalent to a four year course? 
Further, I had percentage system for BSc and CGPA (out of 10) system in the Master's so what would be the conversion factor?

Comment: You will give more information, with less risk of confusion and very little increase in space, if you report each degree on its own line. You can give the actual score for each degree, with an indication of its basis.

Comment: You should report that you have a BSc and an MSc, you should report your BSc average as a percentage, and you should report your MSc average out of 10. **Do not convert anything.**